# jQuery show/hide fields doesn't pass php validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, hide, show

I've a jQuery code which show/hide some disabled fields, based on an user select option:

```
$('.fieldcontent').not('.info').hide();

$('#selector_cs').change(function() {
    $('.fieldcontent').customFadeOut(100);
    $('.' + $(this).val()).customFadeIn(900);
    $('input').prop('disabled',false);
    $('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
    $('select').prop('disabled',false);
});

});
```

The big headache is: if one or more fields are fading in, these fields doesn't pass my php validation, nor submitting the form.

If javascript is disabled on all browsers, the form works perfectly.

PHP validation is

```
if(!isset($_POST['products'])) {
$products[2] = clean_var($_POST['products']);
  }
 else {
  $error = 1;
   $products[3] = 'color:#FF0000;';
  }
```

for all fields

Is there any php /jquery solution (no ajax please, 'cause i won't make the whole form again, and don't know anything about ajax)?

Thanks in advance for help

**EDIT**:  Just detected another error: If the jquery script fadein another section of the form, PHP doesn't validate it anymore. Why? Never had problems like this with php-jquery.

Comment: Could you leave the fields enabled and just hide them instead?

Comment: It's not possibile, because if the fields are enabled AND hidden by jQuery, the php validation wouldn't pass through. If the fields are  disabled, the php validation can't see them. That's the reason why i've disabled the fields if the user doesn't select them.

Comment: make them `type='hidden'` instead? and when you want to show them make them `type='text'` (or something). Leave them enabled though.

Comment: @Someone33 Not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you saying it won't pass PHP validation because the items are fading in/out when the form is submitted?

Comment: @kyle the php validation won't pass because if the fields are fading in, php will not see them any more (with  `if(!isset($_POST['message'])))` ecc.  I know, sound strange. Otherwise, with `if(!empty($_POST['message'])))` the validation woudn't pass. See in google isset vs empty.

Comment: @Someone33 It sounds to me like you are having an issue where you are submitting the form `while` forms are fading in.  To change that, you should have a `boolean flag` that will prevent submission of the form while the fields are fading.  Once the fields have completed the fade, set the boolean back to true.

Comment: @kyle maybe it will be easier to undestand (don't know if my english is correct 100%) the situation if you'll see the files.  Please take a look [HERE](http://zengrafic.com/test/test.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave them enabled, but change the property `type` to `hidden` then PHP should see the fields when you submit them.

**Update**
How about the following scenario:

- 5 fields shown
- start-hiding two fields (A+B)
- 'add' two `type=hidden` fields with the same name as A+B and copy their current value from A+B to `A+`B
- PHP should see these two hidden fields instead of the fields that are currently fading out.
- If the user did not submit while fading out, then when the fields have faded out remove the `A+`B fields and set the property of the two faded fields to `hidden`
- Inverse this for showing them fields again.

Do take note that this is not a problem caused by PHP but caused by how/when a browser interprets a form field to be a valid form field to be send when submitting the form

Comment: If i would leave them enabled, but the fields are not shown by the jQuery script, PHP validation wouldn't pass.                        It's not a problem of seeing the fields or not. The problem is that the validation won't pass. If the fields are fading in, php doesn't recognize the fadeIn fields, 'cause for PHP the new fadedIn fields doesn't exist.

Comment: had tried it, but doesn't work. But maybe i didn't understand what you mean [HERE](http://zengrafic.com/test/test.html) you can see my code in action and download the files. 1000 thanks for help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Just detect that if i'll use hidden fields, PHP would send these hidden fields, which woundn't be pretty to see values like "some1", "some2" ecc. in the mail.